# Odata Global PageSize

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

Can someone please explain why my EnableQueryAttribute filter is not firing when the client query does not include the Count=True in their query? My entire dataset is returned.

```
public class EnableQueryWithDefaultPageSizeAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    const int pageSizeDefault = 100;

    public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        int pagesize = pageSizeDefault;
        var result = queryOptions.ApplyTo(queryable, new ODataQuerySettings { PageSize = pagesize });
        return result;
    }
}
```

The following query trigger the filter:

```
https://localhost:5001/api/teams?$count=true
```

This query doesn't trigger the filter:

```
https://localhost:5001/api/teams
```

The only way to solve it is to right now is to hard code my controller method with:

```
 [EnableQuery(PageSize = 100)]
```

My gold is to have a global filter that sets the page size for any Odata API request.  I've googled and read Microsoft documentation and still can't find a solution.  Any help will be appreciated.  I'm currently using .net core 6.0 and AspNetCoreOdata 8.0.6.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the `ApplyQuery` does the method execute at all?

Comment: Only if the query from the client contains the param count=true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried deliberately setting the property in the constructor? This has the added benefit of still allowing you to override the default page size at each endpoint.

```
public class EnableQueryWithDefaultPageSizeAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public EnableQueryWithDefaultPageSizeAttribute()
    { 
        this.PageSize = 100;
    }
}
```

I think the issue in .Net 5/6 is the paging behaviour needs to be resolvable from the Edm, not from the individual Query, this is a breaking change from the .Net FX implementation when you couldmodify it on a per-request basis.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that the PageSize property need to be set in the constructor.  This seems to fix the issue.